# JSF Primefaces Menu Bootstrap Style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

How to apply Bootstrap menu style in Primefaces `<p:menubar>`

```
<p:layout fullPage="true" style="border:0px;">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="55"  resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true" gutter="0" class="no-border border-bottom ui-menubar">
            <h:form id="frmtheme"> 
                <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />  
                <p:menubar  model="#{menuBean.menubar}"
                    <f:facet name="options" >
                        <h:commandLink action="#{loginBean.doLogout}" value="Log out" class="btn btn-danger logout">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"/>
                        </h:commandLink>

                    </f:facet>
                </p:menubar>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
      </p:layout>
```

As per Bootstrap [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), it requires container `div`s and `<ul>` `<li>` thingies. How can I apply Bootstrap classes here?

Comment: Did you try https://www.bootsfaces.net/ ?

Comment: See also https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/integration/PrimeFaces.jsf

Comment: @JasperdeVries MenuItems are being generated/added at run time. I have downloaded Bootstrap css,js and fonts. I just want to apply these classes.

Comment: PrimeFaces have also a Bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's a good idea to abandon PrimeFaces support with the menu. One of my recent projects used PrimeFaces. But at the same time, they preferred to use the Bootstrap navbar natively. That approach worked great.

Other than that, I agree with Jasper: BootsFaces is the way to go! But I'm a committer to BootsFaces, so I may be biased.